# Auto capitalization of input and TextArea Fields

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have my input Field and is using onKeyup and onKeyPress to return number & characters and then to move to the next field.

```
<input name="aendcodeM" id="aendcodeM" type="text" size="25" maxlength="4" onKeyPress="return numchar(event)" onKeyup="autotab(this, document.form1.bendcodeM)"/>

<input name="bendcodeM" id="bendcodeM" type="text" size="25" maxlength="4" onKeyPress="return numchar(event)" onKeyup="autotab(this, document.form1.bndwdM)"/>
```

I am trying to use feature of auto-capitalization also for which the code witten as -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").keyup(function() {
        var val = $(this).val()
        $(this).val(val.toUpperCase())
    })
})
</script>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").keyup(function() {
        var val = $(this).val()
        $(this).val(val.toUpperCase())
    })
})
</script>
```

```
<script>
$(input[type="text"]).on('keypress', function() { 
    var $this = $(this), value = $this.val(); 
    if (value.length === 1) { 
      $this.val( value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() );
    }  
});

</script>
```

But is of no use since the characters not getting automatically capitalized as desire. Any help in this regard is obliged please.

Thanks & Reagrds

Comment: _Uncaught ReferenceError: autotab is not defined_ error.

Answer (score 7):

Use css **text-transform: uppercase** for your input's **text** & **textarea** elements as:

```
input, textarea{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

This will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Many errors in your code:**

why calling function when it isn't initialized?

> *Uncaught ReferenceError: autotab is not defined* error in demo.

```
<input name="aendcodeM" id="aendcodeM" type="text" size="25" maxlength="4" onKeyPress="return numchar(event)" onKeyup="autotab(this, document.form1.bendcodeM)"/>
                                                                           ^^^^^                               ^^^^
```

Here also `'` is missing:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keypress', function() {
  ^                  ^
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tz4gokmv/1/)

## [How to check Error in console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#errors-and-warnings)

[image]

Comment: Why on earth would you `alert("a");` for every `keypress`? Any why would you assume that the OP is using Chrome?

Comment: I have not assumed that op using chrome. Op and you @indieblue should check for errors before posting on [STACK](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using only one `$(document).ready( ... )` in your Javascript.

[Working demo of your code (fixed)](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/k1kwzfuq/2)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input, textarea").keyup(function() {
        var val = $(this).val()
        $(this).val(val.toUpperCase());
    });

    $('input[type="text"]').on('keypress', function() { 
        var $this = $(this), value = $this.val(); 
        if (value.length === 1) { 
            $this.val( value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() );
        }  
    });
});
```

Comment: _Uncaught ReferenceError: autotab is not defined_ error in demo.

Comment: @Manwal Please check again with your browser cache cleared. I don't have that error in my code!

Comment: I have checked this error and why calling two function for same task in jquery?? -1. You have error in `$(input[type="text"])` `'` quote missing.

Comment: @Manwal I have fixed my answer to have it call one function. Missing quote added.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it that way is unnecessary. I strongly suggest you force uppercase by using the [text-transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp) CSS property.

#### CSS

```
input{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

This will force clients to render text in uppercase at all times.

#### However

Be careful as the values are not. When you proccess your action it is important at that point you convert your value to uppercase either client side or server side.

Comment: Have you tested this? Show us demo.

Comment: This solves the problem - 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function ChangeCase(elem) { elem.value = elem.value.toUpperCase();} 

function numchar(e) {var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode
if (unicode!=8){ if (48 > unicode || (57 < unicode && unicode < 65) || (91 < unicode && unicode < 97) || unicode > 122)  return false } }

function autotab(current,to){.....to.focus()}
</script>

<All Incorporated>
<input name="aendcodeM" id="aendcodeM" type="text" size="25" maxlength="4" onblur="ChangeCase(this)" onkeypress="return numchar(event)" onkeyup="autotab(this, document.form1.bendcodeM)"/>

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i found that when you use variable name same as function name or same as any keyword, then it throws error

so try to do one thing. Also use ids.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#text_area").keyup(function() {
    var valtext = $(this).val()
    $(this).val(valtext.toUpperCase())
})
```

})

Just have a test with this. May be this is the scenario happening on your case

Also use ids.

see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/36bqfms6/

Comment: your answer is wrong smruti and so is his. The problem in the question is because she has not put semicolons and mainly she has not defined her functions autocad and numchar!!!

Comment: who votes up answers like this?

Comment: Read this [Is it okay to copy-paste answers from other questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions)

Comment: its not mandatory to give semicolon at the end of statement... see my fiddle... i also haven't given any semicolon, but still my program runs..

Comment: also did you check my fiddle what i put over there?? in the fiddle also i didnt call any function from the html. I provided the fiddle to give the answer.. After checking the fiddle, its his duty to see what the html is and jquery is.. I pointed the situation tht may happen in his case additionally

Comment: Also @Manwal... somedays ago similar situation had happened when someone else pasted someone else's answer. In that case the paster had been questioned.  Would i have copy pasted your answer, you urself would have commented me like this. Isn't it?

Comment: Want to know who is the generous person who downvoted it?

Answer (score 0):

two things
You have to put semi-colon and also check if this is pointing properly

```
var val = $(this).val();//notice semicolon here
$(this).val(val.toUpperCase());//notice semicolon here
```

Here is your problem. You need to understand the concepts better. You are trying to register event handler both in javascript and jquery. autocad and numchar functions are not defined and since these are event handlers using javscript, when they get hit it wont work.

Find below the code and also check with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wishy/qbfkhz88/

```
<input name="aendcodeM" id="aendcodeM" type="text" size="25" maxlength="4" />

<input name="bendcodeM" id="bendcodeM" type="text" size="25" maxlength="4" />
```

and javascript is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").keyup(function() {

        var val = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(val.toUpperCase());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("textarea").keyup(function() {
    var valtext = $(this).val()
    $(this).val(valtext.toUpperCase())
  });
```

[**Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/a00vx9dj/4/)

The above code is works on all the `textarea` of the page.Firstly we will take take the value of `textarea` where user is start typing then make it `Upper case` using inbuilt function of jquery and assign to the textarea.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: Hi the the above code is works on all the textarea of the page.Firstly we will take take the value of textarea where user is start typing then make it `Upper case` using inbuilt function of jquery and assign to the textarea.

Comment: Don't tell me in the comments. I was suggesting that explaining your code is *part* of your complete answer... so you have to edit your answer and explain it for all the newbies out there. ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Check the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wwf1ea83/)

### Jquery Code

```
$('[type=text]').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val()!=''){
$(this).val( $(this).val().toUpperCase());
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( "#aendcodeM" ).bind( "input", function() {
 $("#aendcodeM").val($("#aendcodeM").val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.